# Dropdown in GWT without <select>

Tags: gwt, domino-ui

We're having a bit of problem. We run Chromium on an embedded platform and when something is selected from a  Chromium crashes. It's not a prioritised bug for the Chromium developers, but it's rather limiting for us.

So the question is if there is some off the shelf widget that gives the same functionality (preferably with the same interface) as GWT's ListBox, but don't use the  tag?

http://dev.arcbees.com/gwtchosen/ may be an option, but it comes with the GQuery baggage.

[Domino UI](https://demo.dominokit.org/) is a material design GUI for GWT, but again it's a bit much for just one control.

Using CSS as https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dropdowns.asp might be another idea.

Update: In the end I just made my own control using a Button that shows a Popuppanel containing a SimplePanel with 1..n Buttons. With some CSS it does an adequate job of replacing the dropdown.

Comment: This might help, a Select implementation without `select` html tag https://demo.dominokit.org/forms/basic-form-elements?theme=indigo

Comment: @RJB Thanks. That is interesting and may be of use for a new project, but like GQuery it comes with an entire GUI kit.